# Include years, months and days in duration response from .toISOString() for MomentJs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

If I set my duration using diff and call .toISOString() I expect to see the relevant years, months and days between the two given dates.

```js
let date1 = new Date('2020-05-20T22:07:33.916Z')
let date2 = new Date('2021-07-24T22:07:33.916Z')

let startMoment = moment(date1)
let endMoment = moment(date2)

const result = moment.duration(endMoment.diff(startMoment, 'months'), 'months').toISOString()

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

However, I expect that string to be **P1Y2M4D** instead of **P1Y2M**